# Use variable in find command

Tags: bash, find

I'm trying to create a simple script that deletes files based on the ending of thier names and the date.

I can't figure out how to do this.

This is how I do it:

```
DA='date +%d'
find /var/www/data/files/ -name "*#$DA*"
```

I want to find all files that ends on this pattern..  So today it would be *#06*

I also tried

```
find . -iname \*${MYVAR}\* -print
```

As suggested here:
http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6234/use-a-variable-in-a-find-command.-useful-in-scripting.

Without luck..

So can anyone help me use the find command searching for a var?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -iname "*$(date +%d)*" -print
```

This should do the trick. With `$()` You can get the output of a command as an argument to another command.

Comment: Similarly, you could do it with `DA=$(date +%d)`, but unless you want it for something else, there's no real point in putting it in a variable first.